# How to rewrite this URL using .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am basically just trying to write a .htaccess redirect that turns the url

`www.example.com/Artist/Profile?Artist='test'` to `www.example.com/Artist/test`

without actualy redirecting the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following directive

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)artist='([^&]+)' [NC]
RewriteRule ^Artist/Profile$ /Artist/%2? [L,NC]
```